# How to display input with the click of a button in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been reading about text-fields but I can't figure it out.. I want to be able to type in a name and age, and then when I press the button "add", I want to be able to see the name and age displayed below. What is the easiest or best way of doing this?

My code:

```
<v-container>
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
    <v-text-field label="Name" solo></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
    <v-text-field label="Age" solo></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  
  <div class="addbutton">
        <v-btn color="green darken-1" large v-on:click="add">Add</v-btn>
  </div>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the variables in the data of your vue component and the use it to render

```
 <v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
    <v-text-field label="Name" solo></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
    <v-text-field label="Age" solo></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  
  <div class="addbutton">
        <v-btn color="green darken-1" large v-on:click="add">Add</v-btn>
  </div>
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" v-if="render!==null">
    <p>{{ render.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ render.age }}</p>
</v-row>

<script>
    export default {
data(){
    return {
    name:null,
    age:null,
    render:null,
},

methods(){
    add(){
        const name = this.name;
        const age = this.age;
        this.render = {
            name,
            age
        }
    },
}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Any idea of why I get this error: ';' expected for methods() and add()?

Comment: Sorry, add a comma after the age value in data

Answer (score 1):

First you should bind inputs to the component data using **v-model**.

script:

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      name: null,
      age: null
    }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
  <v-text-field label="Name" solo v-model="name"></v-text-field>
</v-col>
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
  <v-text-field label="Age" solo v-model="age"></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

Now you can display current inputs values: `<p>{{ name + ', ' + age }}</p>`

If you want to show/hide them with a button, you can add a data property to store their state, create a method to toggle it and bind their visibility to the property using **v-if**:

script:

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      name: null,
      age: null,
      showValues: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.showValues = !this.showValues
    }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
    <v-text-field label="Name" solo v-model="name"></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
    <v-text-field label="Age" solo v-model="age"></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
  
  <div class="addbutton">
        <v-btn color="green darken-1" large @click="toogle">Add</v-btn>
  </div>
  <p v-if="showValues">{{ name + ', ' + age }}</p>
</v-row>
```

Comment: thanks I tried to follow your code but when I click on the Add button, nothing happens. What could cause this?